# Thee.js. textures from canvas refers to the lastone

Tags: three.js

I'm creating some textures for a tiled map. 
I have 10 images. I put every one on canvas (to see it), then create a texture from canvas.
I think there is some persitent link to the canvas because the 10 textures created  are equal to another (the last one).

Are three.js saving some information relative to the canvas and the 'neeedsUpdate' means that the same canvas is used ? (and if the process is fast I have the same canavas image for every one of 10 ?)

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Can you share the exact commands that you're using to create a texture from the canvas?

Comment: @AdiLevin mmm Finally I have discover some strange behaviour with the onload event of img. Even if I have the image inside a blob (not a external resource) I must to take into account the async behaviour. thanks any way

Comment: Glad you succeeded. :-)